# What kind of algebraic structure does java type system follow?

Tags: java, types

What kind of algebraic structure, does java type system follow?

I suspect partiel ordered set, but have problem finding research papers that verify this.

I know null is subtype of everything, and every type is a subtype of Object.

Antisymmetric property is enforced, by removing cyclic inheritance (A extends B, B extends C, C extends A)

Reflexive property is enforced, by remvoing self cyclic inheritance (A extends A)

And transivity is enforced by A extends B, B extends C => A extends C.

It seems like java type system is a partiel ordered set, but cant find any research paper verifying this.

Comment: I think this question is more suited to https://cs.stackexchange.com/